# Is it necessary to always exclude cglib when using hibernate-entitymanager?

Tags: hibernate

Wasted a lot of time configuring my project and finally find out that I have to exclude cglib from my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is it necessary to always exclude cglib? Why is it not excluded by default? And even worse, why there's not anything said about this in the official Hibernate docs?

Comment: Why did you remove the cglib dependency? Was there a problem?